# Trac - get programmatically wiki page content behind authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, wget, trac

I'd like to get the content of a wiki page from my trac (1.0.9) using a script.
My Trac is served through apache httpd and adopts a Basic AuthType.

So I tried to use `wget` as follows

```
wget http://my/trac/wiki/MyWikiPage?format=txt --user=<THISISME> --ask-password --auth-no-challenge -q -O -
```

but I get a 403 error.

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
```

Is there something wrong? Or in other words, is thre a way to simply fetch remotely a wiki page from Trac (taking authentication into account)? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install [XmlRpcPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin) and use one of the [supported libraries](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin#Example), such as `xmlrpclib` in Python, to fetch the page.

Comment: wonderful! By the way I was also looking for a java implementation, and I see It's also there https://trac-hacks.org/raw-attachment/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin/trac_xml_rpc_example_java.zip